# Nunit action attribute: Don't run AfterTest method if any exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, nunit

How to prevent running AfterTest method if there is any exception in testmethod?

```
public class TestAttribute : Attribute, ITestAction
    {
        public void BeforeTest(TestDetails testDetails)
        {
            // Run before test
            // ....
        }

        public void AfterTest(TestDetails testDetails)
        {
            // don't run it if there is any exception
            // how to check whether an exception is thrown from Nunit

            // ...
        }

        public ActionTargets Targets { get; private set; }
    }

[Test][TestAttribute]
public void TestMthod()
{
   throw new Exception("test exception");
}
```

Is there a way to know if an exception is thrown or assert failed in AfterTest method?

Note: I'm not interested in details of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

if an exception is thrown in your TestMthod then the result will be an error not a failure, hence i believe in your current code block you can simply take advantage of the test context like this:

```
    public void AfterTest(TestDetails testDetails)
    {
        if(TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.State == TestState.Error)
        {
            return;   
        } 
        // don't run it if there is any exception
        // how to check whether an exception is thrown from Nunit

        // ...
    }
```

If you are interested in finding out as to what the actual result string is, i think you will need to use the addins and implement an eventlistener.

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried that and the TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.State always returns Success irrepective whether exception or Assert.Fail()

Comment: Version: 2.6.2.12296

Comment: can you try : TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status?

Comment: Status is always Passed and State is always Success

Comment: My appologies, these values wont be of any use to you unless called in the teardown method of this class. Is there a reason why you are not using Setup and teardown instead or the before and after?